# make a bat file that asks what game I want to play

Tags: batch-file

My idea was to have it start when the computer boots and then ask me what game do I want to play. That's simple but I want to be able to answer different answers like: Is the input like CS:GO,cs,csgo,counter strike, and so forth and, here's how I tried to do it=

```
if %game%==1,CS:GO,cs:go,csgo,"Counter Strike","counter strike" goto cs
```

But as you probably know, it did not work. so the question is how to make it so that "%game%" can be a lot of different things and still goes to the same thing without having to do multiply if %GAME%==...?

and here's the whole code if you want to see it=

```
@echo off
color a
cls
:start
echo what game do you want to play?
echo 1/"CS:GO"? -"Counter Strike: Global Ofensive"
echo 2/"H&G"? -"Heros & Generals"
echo 3/"P2"? -"Portal 2"
echo 4/"UT"? -"Unturned"
echo 5/"LO"? -"Loadout"
echo 6/"DAB"? -"Double Action Boogaloo"
set /p game=vwhat game?:
if %game%==1,CS:GO,cs:go,csgo,"Counter Strike","counter strike" goto cs
pause
goto start
```

Comment: You can't. You need multiple statements.

Comment: ok thats bad but thanks for the help and sorry for the grammar mistakes

Answer (score 0):

```
:start
echo what game do you want to play?
echo 1/"CS:GO"? -"Counter Strike: Global Ofensive"
echo 2/"H&G"? -"Heros & Generals"
echo 3/"P2"? -"Portal 2"
echo 4/"UT"? -"Unturned"
echo 5/"LO"? -"Loadout"
echo 6/"DAB"? -"Double Action Boogaloo"
set /p game=what game?: 
echo /1/CS:GO/csgo/Counter Strike/ |find /i "/%game%/">nul && goto cs
rem other games here...
pause
goto start
```

`/i` makes the `find`case insensitive, so it will find CSGO, CsGo, cSgO,...

`&&` works as "if previous command (`find`) was successful, then..."